# GWT: avoid setting window.name on web application load

Tags: gwt

I wanted to use window.name as a holder for some identifier to use whenever page refresh happens (or being forced). However, I've noticed that GWT sets it to `rename-to` property value defined in module definition. Is there any way to avoid it?

P.S. I know I can use sessionStorage, or maybe even some other mechanism. I'm just curious about this specific case -- would like to know how could I override such GWT behavior.

Comment: Are you sure the window is getting its name changed? I recall that the module changes the iframe that it loads into, but not the global window. Or are you using a different linker? Or referring to the window as `window` in your jsni instead of `$wnd`?

Comment: You are totally right. Now as I read through JSNI doc I learned about $wnd and $doc.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your final solution as answer.

Comment: @Colin Alworth I'll gladly accept your answer if you simply repost comment as an answer. It was beginners mistake but it also can be done by someone else who doesn't work with GWT on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the window is getting its name changed? I recall that the module changes the iframe that it loads into, but not the global window. Or are you using a different linker? Or referring to the window as window in your jsni instead of `$wnd`?

```
private native void setWindowName(String newName) /*-{
  $wnd.name=newName;
}-*/;
```